# XPath to catch a specific text value of <li> but not its child element

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have this tricky situation of web scraping. Where I want to catch some specific text value that has been stored very complicatedly in DOM. I am new to XPath have gone through its basics and certain other questions, but couldn't solve this issue.
I will explain this using 2 pictures.

**Data to capture:**

[image: data to capture]

**Below is its HTML structure:**

```
<h3>Alias names of NEUROD2 Gene</h3>
<div class="some-col-name-8">
    <ul class="list-unstyled list-spacious">
        <li>
            <span id="aliasMainName">Neuronal Differentiation 2</span>
            <sup>...</sup>
            <sup>...</sup>
            .
            .
            <sup></sup>
        </li>
        <li>
            "
            Text11   "
            <sup></sup>
            <sup></sup>
            </li>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>
            <span class="hilite">NeuroD</span>
            "-Related Factor"
            <sup>...</sup>
            <sup>
                <a class="usp we-we-link" target="_blank" href="http:www.uniprot.org/uniprot/23423" title="Uniprot">
                </a>
            </sup>
        </li>
        <li>...</li>
```

So as you can see above that the text present between the dynamic number of **li** tags. Here the text is needed without the superscript numbers.

That is I want to skip out its child **sup** tag. 
Like in case of **NeuroD-Related factor & NeuroD2** in above image, I want *NeuroD-Related factor* & *NeuroD2* as one text, **not NeuroD separated from "Related Factor" and "2"**.

I have used:
`//*[@id="some_id"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li/*`.

Which *gives only just child* of **li**, which solves the skipping of **sup** tags but it also omits out the element like **-Related Field** and **2**. In **NeuroD**.

How to go about such a problem with XPath.
Please, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you share the link of the webpage as well so we can test on our systems as well

Comment: Share appropriate HTML sample as text, not as image

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based HTML and code trials.

Comment: @DebanjanB I wasn't aware of it before. The question has been updated. Thanks for your information.

Comment: @NimishBansal the link is http://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=NEUROD2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you talk about this page http://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=NEUROD2

In pure XPath you would apply something like

```
//li//text()[not(ancestor::sup)]
```

to get text from each `li` ignoring text from `sup`... But Selenium doesn't support this syntax.

**As last resort** you can apply little hack to hide `sup` nodes and get only required text of each `li`:

```
driver.execute_script("""document.querySelectorAll("#aliases_descriptions sup").forEach(function(i) 
                        {i.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden");});""")
required_text_nodes = [li.text for li in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//section[@id="aliases_descriptions"]//h3[.="Aliases for NEUROD2 Gene"]/following-sibling::div//li')]
```

*Output of `print(required_text_nodes)`:*

```
['Neuronal Differentiation 2', 'Class A Basic Helix-Loop-Helix Protein 1', 'Neurogenic Differentiation 2', 'NeuroD-Related Factor', 'BHLHa1', 'NDRF', 'Neurogenic Basic-Helix-Loop-Helix Protein', 'Neurogenic Differentiation Factor 2', 'NeuroD2']
```

P.S. After you got text you can make `sup` nodes visible again:

```
driver.execute_script("""document.querySelectorAll("#aliases_descriptions sup").forEach(function(i) 
                            {i.setAttribute("style", "visibility: visible");});""")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man! really to the point. I am amazed. And you know the website also, have you worked on this website before.

Comment: I simply checked Google search results for "Alias names of NEUROD2 Gene"... :)

Comment: Can you please have a look at this problem 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219383/selenium-on-chrome-drive-running-on-server-as-a-part-of-website-is-in-excessable which I am unable to get my head around. Any sources, guess or direction which I should proceed it would be very helpful. @Andersson

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no direct way to get this using XPath, I may be wrong. But You can use a couple of loops to do the required. You can use following logic:-

1. Get list of all `li`
2. Get Text of `li`, it will be text required + text not required from `sup` tag
3. Get all child of current `li` and loop through them to get text of `sup` tag.
4. Replace now text from sup in earlier text of li.

I have never used python and I may be wrong in syntax but this is how I think it would be --

```
listParent = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id]')  # Id of parent of the list.
list = listParent.find_elements_by_xpath('//li')
for li in list:
    data = li.text
    sups = li.find_elements_by_xpath('.//sup')
    text=''
    for sup in sups
        text = text + sup.text

requiredText = string.replace(data, text, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following xpath to exclude sup tag.

```
//*[@id="some_id"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li/node()[not(local-name()="sup"]
```

simply xpath,

```
//ul/li/node()[not(local-name()="sup"]
```

It returns all nodes which include text nodes as well. But selenium doesn't support text node as return type in java. We can take help of javascript. The following code may works.

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Projects\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    driver.get("file:///C:/Projects/testing2.html");
    String value="";
    String script;
    List<WebElement> lstElements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul/li"));
    for(int i=1;i<=lstElements.size();i++){
        script="var iterator=document.evaluate('//ul/li["+i+"]/node()[not(local-name()=\"sup\")]', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);"+
                " var text='';"+
                "try {"+
                     "var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();"+
                     "while (thisNode) {"+
                        "text=text.concat(thisNode.textContent);"+
                        "thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();"+
                      "}"+  
                 "}"+
                 "catch (e) {"+
                       " dump('Error: Document tree modified during iteration ' + e );"+
                "} return text;";
        value = (String)jse.executeScript(script);
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    driver.quit();
```

You can change the script for python. It should works